# How to cache Images & JS files on static HTML page

Tags: html, browsers, cache-control

I want to cache image & JS files on a static webpage. and trying to improve browser cache score, after adding following tag it doesn't make any difference to the cache score which remains at 49.

Will adding meta  `http-equiv="cache-control"` adding caching for all elements on page or not

[image]

`<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=864000" />`

Is there a simple way of adding cache property to images and JS files

`<script src='<%= ResolveUrl ("~/assets/js/main.js?v=1.0.9x") %>'></script>`

`<img src="../images/logo.png"/>`

Webpage are hosted on windows server so `.htaccess` is not supported how can we configure same in windows hosted environment
with `.htaccess` it was easy as i had to add only following code to file

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Answer (score 1):

To leverage Browser Caching on Windows Host, assuming it's IIS, you have to add this snippet in the `web.config` file in the document root of your website:

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

The `cacheControlMaxAge` setting will tell how much time all static ressources should be cached, here it is set to 30 days.